# Raspberry Pi 3 as Terminal from wifi to ethernet

Tags: networking

I have in my school a wifi network and a ethernet network. These networks are not connected to each over. This means that the school PCs have a 172.16.83.XXX IP address and the devices that connected to the wifi have a 10.0.4.XXX IP address.

**Now my question:**
Is it possible to use a Raspberry Pi 3 as a terminal from wifi to ethernet? Means that i connect for example with my smartphone to the Pi (Pi connected to WiFi and Ethernet) and connect from the Pi to a PC.

**Example:**
Smartphone SSH Client (10.0.4.8) -> Pi (10.0.4.9) -> PC[for example: ubuntu] (172.16.83.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pi could be connected to both networks simultaneously, which would allow you to ssh into the Pi from either the wireless or the wired networks.  Each network interface would have it's own IP address on the respective subnet.

Since the Pi will be on the school's network, there may be multiple Pi units connected by other students. So, I would recommend either turning off `avahi` or changing your RPi hostname to something other than `raspberrypi`.

```
sudo systemctl stop avahi-daemon && systemctl disable avahi-daemon
```

or

```
sudo hostnamectl myRPihostname && systemctl restart avahi-daemon
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to make your Pi act as a router between the wireless and wired networks?

Yes, it can do that.

Have you tried this guide?
https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point.pdf

Comment: I don’t know what would be the best method.. My idea was to give the Pi a 10.0.4.X and a 172.16.83.X IP (If it works). So that i can connect of any Access Point in the school to the Pi and then to a PC. And it‘s very important for me that the PC isn‘t/that the PCs aren‘t connected directly to the Ethernet Port of the Pi (or to a switch that‘s connected to the Pi). Means that the PCs should be connected to the normal ethernet Switch.

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, answers should not require clarification from the author.